# Powershell equivalent to $_ in bash

Tags: bash, shell, powershell, sh, automatic-variable

In bash, to get argument from last command we call `$_`. 
I have searched but couldn't find what is equivalent to bash's `$_` in PowerShell ?
Example:

```
$ mkdir 20171206
$ cd $_
```

Now bash current working directory would be `20171206` and I am trying to achieve same via PowerShell.

Is it possible ?

Comment: The PowerShell equivalent of that command would be `mkdir 20171206 | cd`.

Comment: You didn't really explain what bash's `$_` does.  I would start by looking at [`Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Agree with @BaconBits, but Ansgars comment wasn't intended to answer the question and showed how to do it the PowerShell way. IMHO it's important tu use one language's features instead of trying to rebuild another languages functionality.

Comment: So, we can achieve it some way. thats all I need. have a great day team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `$_` in bash means "last argument of previous command".

The closest approximation of that is `$$`, which is [defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1) as:

> Contains the last token in the last line received by the session.

However, I don't know if that means PowerShell's `$$` [behaves like bash's `$_` or if it behaves like bash's `!$`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271659/vs-last-argument-of-the-preceding-command-and-output-redirection).  I think it's closer to `!$`, but I'm on my Chromebook at the moment and can't confirm.

Edit:  It's like `!$`:

```
PS C:\> Get-Location > a.txt
PS C:\> $$
a.txt
```

So there's no direct equivalent to bash's `$_`.

Keep in mind, though, that PowerShell strongly favors objects and pipes, so retaining the bash convention of thinking about everything in terms of plain text and space-delimited tokens won't serve you as well.  The best way to do this in PowerShell is:

```
mkdir 20171206 | cd
```

Or, if you're not using any of the default PowerShell aliases and functions (I'm not sure what gets retained on Linux PowerShell, for example):

```
New-Item 20171206 -ItemType Directory | Set-Location
```